# Windows phone strings and localization

Tags: string, localization, resources, windows-phone

A vanilla Windows Phone device is populated with many string resources - for example 'Settings' and beneath 'Settings' lies 'location' among others. At least this is the case for the en-GB UI language. I would like to access the full list of device-loaded strings, not just for en-GB, but for every UI-supported language. That is, I'm looking for the full list of en-GB UI strings, plus their parallel translations in the full set of UI-supported languages. Can anyone help me find them? Do I need a special SDK? Does Microsoft simply 'publish' them somewhere? Or do I need to write some C# to query an on-phone assembly?

Comment: I can at last add that the answer from @Matt-Lacey below is as good as I've been able get. So an uptick for him. I'd be interested to know from someone with an MSDN/TechNet subscription if the required files are offered here: http://www.microsoft.com/Language/en-US/Translations.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strings used by the OS and the native apps are not available via any public method.

If you are looking to translate your app you need to translate text in context to where you use it. It is not a straight copy and paste exercise. This means you can't just reuse the translations from another source. (Unless it's the exact same context.)

Comment: Actually, it is the exact same context. I'm building an app and the documentation will be translated into multiple languages. In the docs, I would like to get the user to perform actions against core WP functionality - e.g. 'Press **Settings** and then **location**'. I can't ask my translator to translate Settings and location, because they've already been translated by Microsoft and any new attempt at translation might substitute the wrong word.